# Python - Pandas CSV file with error when converting mixed data types string to number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

So I have a large csv file with lots of data. The main column 'Results', that I am interested in has integers, float, NaN data types and also number as text. I need to aggregate 'Results' but before I do I want to convert the column to float data type. The values that are text have trailing spaces like the following:
["1.07  ", "8.22     ", "8.6      ", "11.41     ", "7.93       "]

The error I get is...

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

csv_file = 'c:/path/to/file/big.csv'
# ... more lines of code ...

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=my_cols, parse_dates=['Date'])
df = df[df['Company ID'].str.contains(my_company)]
print('df of csv created')
# Above code works great. 

# the below 2 tries did not work for me
# df['Result'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Result'].str.replace(' ', ''), errors='ignore')
# df['Result'] = df['Result'].str.strip() # causes an error 

# now let's try np.where...
# the below causes AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! 
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Result'].dtype == np.str, df['Result'].str.strip(), 
df['Result'])
df['Result'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Result'], downcast="float", errors='raise')
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: If I remove the line `df['Result'] = np.where(df['Result'].dtype == np.str, df['Result'].str.strip(), 
df['Result'])`
I get an error `ValueError: Unable to parse string "             " at position 1283`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this code to explicitly convert all the value as stirng using `astype(str)`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Result': [' a ', ' b', 'c ']
})

df['Result'] = df['Result'].astype(str).str.strip()
print(df['Result'])

#0    a
#1    b
#2    c
#Name: Result, dtype: object
```

Sometime, I use this code if NaN or numbers are included in a Series to avoid getting the error msg.

Comment: I did use this method but I modified it, because I got `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'` So I did 2 steps. `df['Result'] = df['Result'].astype(str)` then `df['Result'] = df['Result'].str.strip()`

Comment: @Shane Oh, sorry I forgot to add '`str` inside there. You can do it by one line. I just edited my code with sample dataset. Thank you for pointing out :)